# how to prove this function is increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

i asked about thisfunction before but no one respond
 \begin{eqnarray*}
\Gamma(x+1)>\frac{\frac{(900\gamma^2+73\pi^2)x}{900\gamma}+\frac{73}{100}}{\frac{\pi^2 x}{9\gamma}+1}\quad [1]
\end{eqnarray*}
, \begin{eqnarray*}
1\leq x\leq0
\end{eqnarray*}
,
i want to prove this inequality **(prove it is an increasing )**
by "L’HospitalPiecewise MonotoneRules"
i put it as

\begin{eqnarray*}
T(x)=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)-\frac{\frac{(900\gamma^2+73\pi^2)x}{900\gamma}+\frac{73}{100}}{\frac{\pi^2 x}{9\gamma}+1}}{x-1}\quad 
\end{eqnarray*}
and divided it on (x-1) such that 
$f(x)=\Gamma(x+1)-\frac{\frac{(900\gamma^2+73\pi^2)x}{900\gamma}+\frac{73}{100}}{\frac{\pi^2 x}{9\gamma}+1}$
and $g(x)=x-1$

but By the well-known software Mathematica  gives me it not increasing

what the formula that can i get it from [1] to prove it increasing??

Comment: What is the range of $x$?

Comment: for x on (0,1)............

Comment: Why would you expect M'ma to tell you this difference is increasing?  The difference has a minimum around x = 0.6.

Comment: $1 \leq x \leq 0$ excludes all possible $x$.

Comment: What does it mean for an inequality to be increasing? I understand increasing functions and increasing sequences, but I never learned about increasing inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

A reference for the obscure "L’HospitalPiecewise MonotoneRules":  Pinelis, I. "[L'Hospital-Type Rules for Monotonicity: ...](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9761/6867142053a490f50b0e9a5455d1e5b4d8ac.pdf)"

Using Pinelis's "General Rules for Monotonicity" (p. 8), we can show that $\Gamma(x) / r(x)$ (for definition of $r$, see below) has a single local minimum on $(0,1)$, but we seem to have to use the same methods as below to show that minimum is ${}> 1$.

---

First, $$  \frac{\frac{(900\gamma^2+73\pi^2)x}{900\gamma}+\frac{73}{100}}{\frac{\pi^2 x}{9\gamma}+1} = \frac{657 \gamma  + (900 \gamma^2 + 73 \pi^2)x}{900 \gamma + 100 \pi^2 x}  \text{,}  $$
so let's give that rational function a name: 
$$ r(x) = \frac{657 \gamma  + (900 \gamma^2 + 73 \pi^2)x}{900 \gamma + 100 \pi^2 x}  \text{.}  $$

If $\Gamma(x+1) > r(x)$, then 
$$  (900 \gamma + 100 \pi^2 x)\Gamma(x+1) - (657 \gamma  + (900 \gamma^2 + 73 \pi^2)x) > 0  \text{.}  $$  The minimum of 
$$  (900 \gamma + 100 \pi^2 x)\Gamma(x+1) - (657 \gamma  + (900 \gamma^2 + 73 \pi^2)x)  $$
is $1.7788\dots$, attained at $x = 0.61204\dots$.

Mathematica will happily tell you this.

```
Minimize[{
  Gamma[x + 1] 100 (9 EulerGamma + Pi^2 x) 
    - (657 EulerGamma + 900 EulerGamma^2 x + 73 Pi^2 x), 
  0 < x < 1
}, x] // N

(*  {1.77889, {x -> 0.612041}}  *)
```

Another way to get M'ma to tell you that $\Gamma(x+1) > r(x)$ is

```
r[x_] := (657 EulerGamma + 900 EulerGamma^2 x + 73 Pi^2 x)/(100 (9 EulerGamma + Pi^2 x))
Minimize[{Gamma[x + 1] - r[x], 0 < x < 1}, x] // N

(*  {0.00158229, {x -> 0.613441}}  *)
```

so $\Gamma(x+1) > r(x) + 0.0015822$ for $0<x<1$.

If you wish to, by hand, show your inequality, you will need to be able to evaluate derivatives of $\Gamma$.  However, if you can accept a bunch of numbers from nowhere that happen to work, the line 
$$  s(x) = (0.12309) (x - 0.61344) + 0.894  $$
has the property 
$$  \Gamma(x+1) > s(x) > r(x)  $$
for $0 < x < 1$.  The right half is easy.  I don't know about showing the left half without calculus and a bunch of numerical estimates.

Comment: thanks a lot for solve and for helping  ,i need to prove it by "L’HospitalPiecewise MonotoneRules" so i try  put it in up as two function f(x) ,g(x)

Comment: @HM : If a specific method must be used, that information should be in your Question.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wolfy,
the inequality holds,
there are no positive roots
for the difference,
and the expansion of the difference at zero is

$27/100 - 2 \gamma x + ( \gamma ^2/2 + (7 π^2)/36) x^2 + ...
$